# Hide/Show Input Text Not Accepting Diacritics When In type="password"

Tags: javascript, css, passwords

I am not a front-end developer. Nobody on my team knows how to answer this question. In our codebase, any time there is a secure answer (password, confirmation code, security questions, etc), we have the option to Hide/Reveal text inputs. In my case, this is implemented with type=(revealed ? "text" : "password"), which seems to be an old standard. When the input is "text", diacritics are handled in the expected way. On a mac, you can press 'Option' + 'n' + 'a' to get 'ã'. You can also long-press the 'a' key, and click your intended letter.

However, when type="password", it simply ignores the 'Option' + 'n', resulting in just the letter 'a'. If you long-press 'a', it repeats that letter multiple times. Currently, the only way to have the hidden text accept such unicode characters is by copy-pasting them into the input.

I believe these are the relevant code sections, slightly obfuscated only if necessary:

```
const RevealContainer = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  bottom: ${props =>
    (getInputHeight(props.size) - getLinkButtonHeight(revealLinkSize)) / 2}px;
  line-height: normal;
`;
```

```
Input.defaultProps = {
  type: "text",
  autoFocus: false,
  disabled: false,
  invalid: false,
  autoComplete: "off",
  autoCorrect: "off",
  spellCheck: "false",
  large: false,
  maxLength: 255,
  focused: false,
  locked: false,
  size: SIZES.MEDIUM
};
```

```
  render() {
    const revealed = this.props.revealed || this.state.revealed;

    return (
      <PasswordInputContainer>
        <InputWithReveal
          {...this.props}
          type={revealed ? "text" : "password"}
        />
// This is where I put the meow div I mention in the next section. <div>Meow</div>
        <RevealContainer size={this.props.size}>
          <LinkButton onClick={this.toggleReveal} size={revealLinkSize}>
            {revealed ? (
              <FormattedMessage defaultMessage="Hide" />
            ) : (
              <FormattedMessage defaultMessage="Show" />
            )}
          </LinkButton>
        </RevealContainer>
      </PasswordInputContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

I have verified that multiple websites with password inputs handle diacritics properly, and have googled many variations of this problem, to no avail. A coworker suggested that this involved React Select, which contained the undocumented properties of ignoreAccents and ignoreCase which supposedly defaults to true. However, there was no difference in behavior when I changed the following section to include those values set to false:

```
PasswordInput.defaultProps = {
  autoFocus: false,
  invalid: false,
  autoComplete: "off",
  autoCorrect: "off",
  spellCheck: "false",
  ignoreAccents: false,
  ignoreCase: false,
  maxLength: 255,
  revealed: false,
  size: SIZES.MEDIUM
};
```

(For the record, I tried both "false" as a string and false as a bool).

I have verified that I am working in the proper code area by inserting a <div>Meow</div> into the render() function and observed that a Meow appeared next to the Hide button.

If this is not enough info, I will be happy to supply more; I appreciate any help!

Edit to add:

After I found the phrase "dead keys", I was able to find an old bug report against chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=367103
I tried the show/hide passwords for our site and several others on chrome, safari, and firefox. Firefox worked as expected for all of them, while chrome and safari all showed the same problem for all sites. So I guess this is a browser issue?

Comment: I have the same problem, you're not alone